# PDF attach file/binary

Tags: linux, xml, pdf

Is it possible to attach a file to a PDF?

A PDF invoice is generated from a XML file. Is it possible somehow to "attach" the original XML source to the PDF?

JPG images are attached to PDF as an object...

I need a solution from command line in `Linux`

Comment: What tool are you using to generate the PDF in the first place? Many formatters can add PDF File Attachments in the process of generating the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PDFs can have attachments. You can do this manually in, say, Adobe Acrobat, or with a command line tool. For example, with [cpdf](https://www.coherentpdf.com/) (disclaimer, which I wrote):

```
cpdf -attach-file invoice.xml in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

Such attachments then show up in Adobe Reader, and may be extracted or viewed by the user.

Comment: How will it attach the file and how is it accessible from the PDF? Will there be a link in the PDF file?

Comment: No, the PDF reader will show a list of attached files. I think in Adobe Reader it's on the left hand side, as an alternative to the bookmarks or thumbnails view. But other readers may not support attachments at all, of course...

Comment: Do you have a link to your tool and some documentation both to your tool and the attachment feature in the PDF format?

Comment: @clarkk Modesty or caution may have prevented John Whitington from linking to his tool, but I went ahead and updated the answer with a link to the cpdf website.